# iOS - Xcode - Compiling Depenent Builds

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

I have a iOS/Xcode project which contains all of my application logic. I have created a new project which contains the automated test cases for my primary project. My primary project is a dependent of the test project. Now every time I build the primary project, Xcode builds the test target. So far so good.

However if any of the cases in the test project fails, Xcode displays a red symbol next to the failed case but continues building my primary project.

My question is, can I force Xcode to abort the compilation process if any test case in my dependent project fails?